# The docx is empty after converting it from pdf

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to do a PDF to DOCX converter as my first project, but I have some issues with it. Working with Flask.

This is my app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class PDFFile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']


def pdf_to_docx(pdf_path, docx_path):
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    doc = Document()

    for page_num in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text("text")
        doc.add_paragraph(text)

    doc.save(docx_path)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pdf_file = request.files.get('file')
        docx_data = request.form.get('docx-data')

        if not pdf_file or not allowed_file(pdf_file.filename) or not docx_data:
            return redirect(request.url)

        filename = secure_filename(pdf_file.filename)
        pdf_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        docx_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f"{filename}.docx")

        pdf_file.save(pdf_path)
        print(f"PDF file saved to: {pdf_path}")
        pdf_to_docx(pdf_path, docx_path)

        pdf_file_data = open(pdf_path, 'rb').read()
        upload = PDFFile(filename=filename, data=pdf_file_data)
        db.session.add(upload)
        db.session.commit()

        docx_file_data = open(docx_path, 'rb').read()
        docx_filename = f"{filename}.docx"
        upload = PDFFile(filename=docx_filename, data=docx_file_data)
        db.session.add(upload)
        db.session.commit()

        return render_template('main_page.html', download_filename=docx_filename)

    return render_template('main_page.html')


@app.route('/download/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(filename):
    file_data = PDFFile.query.filter_by(filename=filename).first()

    if file_data:
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            return send_file(
                io.BytesIO(file_data.data),
                as_attachment=True,
                attachment_filename=file_data.filename,
                mimetype='application/octet-stream'
            )
        else:
            return "File not found on the server"
    else:
        return "File data not found in the database"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The program is kind of basic, upload your pdf press convert and download it as docx.
The problem is after I upload it and press convert, the docx is empty and I don't understand really why.

Comment: What is the document?  You are pulling the text from the PDF.  If the PDF happens to be a set of scanned pages, as they sometimes are, then there is no text to be had.  Are you sure your users will be expecting you to keep a copy of all of their data?

Comment: PDF are for containing instructions on how to draw a graphic. That the PDF might also contain the text to be drawn is coincidental and not strictly necessary. As a result it's entirely possible (though not common) to have a PDF that produces a graphic of text but the text itself is nowhere to be found in the PDF file. This typically happens with scanned documents though there is software that can apply OCR to the scan and embed the resulting text in the PDF.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for answering, I was trying to pull text from an ebook, which was not scanned.

About this "Are you sure your users will be expecting you to keep a copy of all of their data?" -> I deleted the db, I saw a solution on youtube that includes the db, but is not working.